# Python - merge two datasets based on Date - one has daily date the other has timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I am trying to merge two Python dataframe that look like:

```
df1.head()
Out[36]: 
         Date       Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close     Volume
0  2009-12-31  30.447144  30.478571  30.080000  30.104286  26.061205   88102700
1  2010-01-04  30.490000  30.642857  30.340000  30.572857  26.466835  123432400
2  2010-01-05  30.657143  30.798571  30.464285  30.625713  26.512596  150476200
3  2010-01-06  30.625713  30.747143  30.107143  30.138571  26.090879  138040000
4  2010-01-07  30.250000  30.285715  29.864286  30.082857  26.042646  119282800

df2.head()
Out[37]: 
            timestamp  var1
0 2018-05-02 04:53:46         150785
1 2018-05-02 06:38:58         150785
2 2018-05-03 00:35:25         145510
3 2018-05-03 06:33:53         145510
4 2018-05-03 06:48:56         145510
```

using the command:

```
merged1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='timestamp', right_on='Date')
```

gives me an error `ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can cast your 'Date' column to datetime - `df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])` - before merging.

Comment: It throws no errors but the results have 0 rows .. probably can't merge timestamp with date, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df2['Date']=df2['Timestamp'].str[:10]` and then merge on Date. You can't just do `df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])` because of hh:mm:ss that are not empty in df2

Comment: this gives me an error `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: Ok, you need to have the same type to do a merge. df2['Date']=df2['Timestamp'].str[:10].as_type('str')